# PropertyGrid + Description - Still using summary?

Tags: c#

I'm feeling like an idiot asking this, however, do I have to put the <summary> before or after the Category, DisplayName and Description stuff for the PropertyGrid?

```
[Category("Test")]
[DisplayName("Test Property")]
[Description("My description")]
/// <summary>
/// My summary!
/// </summary>
public string TestProperty { get; set; }
```

Also, is it possible to change the value in the PropertyGrid in some cases? For example, I have a Vector3 struct, which is fine -coding wise-, but looks bad in the PropertyGrid. Is there a way to handle that?

And, can I just use the description of the summary as description in the PropertyGrid?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Place the comments before the attributes.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx to answer your second question

Answer (score 2):

If you try to write the forward slash for introducing the XML comment on a line after the Attribute you will notice that autocompletition doesn't start. Instead if you put the forward slash before the attribute the autocompletition kicks in. So I think that this is a strong evidence where the IDE expects to find your summary comment

Answer (score 2):

The comments should be before the attributes.

```
/// <summary>
/// My summary!
/// </summary>
[Category("Test")]
[DisplayName("Test Property")]
[Description("My description")]
public string TestProperty { get; set; }
```

I learned this by typing the property `TestProperty` and hovering over it with the mouse in Visual Studio.  The "My summary!" text appears only when the comments are placed first.

Answer (score 1):

The summary can certainly go above the attributes, and if you're having problems with it under the attributes then move it above. I know in the past that I've had both on objects and I was able to get the description attribute to show.

Finally, to get a custom display for your properties you'll need to build custom display descriptors. That answer is too broad for this question but if you Google them you'll find tons of examples.